# C# BackgroundWorker, DataSet and DataGridView Multithread Updating

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, dataset, backgroundworker

Please note ahead of time this is the first time working with multiple threads and my first attempt to use a second thread to populate/edit a `DataSet` then to display that `DataSet` into a Windows form that is dedicated to the `DataGridView` control. I've read various articles about thread safe code and I believe I'm going about it correctly.

During debugging, the `DataSet` is passed into the `BackgroundWorker` and pulled out of the thread with `e.Result`. Then it's assigned back to the variable that is used throughout the program.

When looking into the memory of the `DataSet` object, it has all the data that is loaded into it when it arrives to the `frmGridView` but the control is never updated.

Here are the pieces of my code. Any recommendations, suggestions, ideas for better code organization/structure would be most helpful. Again, this is my first at bat with `BackgroundWorker`.

Thanks!

**Method Snippets:**

```
   private DataSet ProcessListXml(DataSet _dsData, BackgroundWorker _bwThread)

   ..

   _dsData.Tables["MainList"].BeginLoadData();

   ..

   DataRow row = _dsData.Tables["MainList"].NewRow();

   ..

   _dsData.Tables["MainList"].Rows.Add(row);

   .. 
       _bwThread.ReportProgress((currLine / totalLines) * 100); 
   } //reader.Read()

   ..

   _dsData.Tables["MainList"].EndLoadData();
   _dsData.Tables["MainList"].AcceptChanges();
   return _dsData;
```

**DataGridView Windows Form:**

```
public partial class frmDataView : Form
{

    DataSet dsGameList;

    public frmDataView(DataSet _in)
    {
        dsGameList = _in;
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView.DataSource = dsGameList.Tables["GameList"];
    }

    public void RefreshView()
    {
        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
```

**BackgroundWorker Snippet:**

```
private void bwThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    e.Result = ProcessMameListXml(dsData, worker);
}

private void bwThread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dvProgressBar.UpdateProgressBar(e.ProgressPercentage);
}

private void bwThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dsData = (DataSet)e.Result;
    dvProgressBar.Close();
    UpdateUIElements();
    dvWindow.RefreshView();
}
```